# Identity comparisons of two object()

Tags: python

Identity comparisons in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not) describe that the result of `is` expression depends on object identity.

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for an object’s identity: `x is y` is true if and only if `x` and `y` are the same object. An Object’s identity is determined using the `id()` function. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value.

But the code below shows the different results.

```py
id(object()) == id(object())  # True
object() is object() # False
```

`object() is object()` result must be `True` due to the docs describing.

Comment: that's not a good way to see what's going on. store them as a variable first. what is `object()` here?

Comment: calling `object()` means you are calling a constructor for calls `object`; so basically, you are comparing two different instances of the same class.

Check

`obj = object(); another = obj; obj is another`

Comment: IDs are reused. You're not keeping any references to your objects, and the IDs become available after they are abandoned. In the first test, two objects are created, they don't exist at the same time, and they are given the same ID. In the second test, two objects are directly compared, so they do exist at the same time (and do have different IDs).

Answer (score 4):

calling `object` constructor (I mean `object()`), each time allocates and constructs a new *object* instance with new **available** *id* in the current scope.

```py
a = object()
b = object()

id(a) == id(b)    # False
a is b            # False
```

Python garbage collector, collects objects as soon as they become unusable (e.g. out of the scope, deconstruct object and etc.) and makes the allocated memory free. So their *id* will be available for next objects which will be built in the future.

So in below snippet,

```py
object() is object()            # False
id(object()) == id(object())    # True
```

in the 1st line, two objects are created at the same time to compare, then collected by garbage collector. Thus they have different *id*s and they are not the same.

in the 2nd line, first object is created and it's *id* is extracted to compare, then it's deconstructed (cause collecting by garbage collector). second object use the first available *id*, which is the just collected *id* from the first object. So they have the same *id*!

Comment: How does it explain that `id(object())==id(object())` is `True`?

Comment: @bereal as khelwood also said, the first object is garbage collected before the comparison is finished. So the now freed memory location is reused for the second object, resulting in them having the same id. See [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id): "[...] Two objects with **non-overlapping lifetimes** may have the same `id()` value."

Comment: @bereal I've added some more description to my answer. Let's check it...